# In Perforce, how to get latest version of a binary file (like Excel file) safely, without overriding my local copy?

Tags: excel, file, binary, perforce

I use Perforce to manage a project that contains some binary files (Excel, Word and Visio diagram files).

I'd like to know the safe way to update my local version of such files from the latest version available on Perforce, without corrupting/damaging/overriding the local changes. (Local changes are made locally and not submitted to Perforce yet)

Locks don't seem to solve the problem because it helps only in concurrent submission of files.

Comment: Are you asking how to merge changes with binary file formats? Or are you asking how to use Perforce locking mechanisms to avoid ever having the need for merging changes with binary file formats? (Or maybe you're asking something else entirely?)

Comment: Bryan, asking about how to merge remote binary file to my local binary file, such that I get the remote changes, while keeping any possible local changes.

Comment: Practically, we are working on updating software design document, so many people are updating different sections of a word document. We need to make sure that after someone finishes his part of the document, s/he can safely get the latest version of the document (what other mates have done) without losing the part s/he's written

Comment: MS Word might not be the best choice of tool for maintaining this document.  If you want to keep it in Perforce, I'd use markdown format, since that merges *very* well (even using Perforce's built-in plain text merge) and is easy to edit/view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `p4 reconcile` to make sure that any local changes are correctly reflected in your pending changelist(s).
2. `p4 sync` as normal.  Opened files will not be overwritten by a `p4 sync`.

If you're following the standard Perforce workflow of always opening files for edit before you modify them (i.e. you never override the "read-only" flag on your local files), you can skip step 1 and just `sync` at any time without fear.

3. `p4 resolve` to handle any files that have been modified both locally and in the depot.

Note that Perforce's built-in merge logic will only handle text files, and so `resolve` will by default offer only a binary yours/theirs choice for binary files (`at` will overwrite your local changes, and `ay` will ignore the depot changes).  If you have a merge tool that can handle your binary format, you can do:

```
p4 set P4MERGE=your_merge_tool
p4 resolve -t
m
```

to invoke your merge tool as part of the `resolve` process.  See the documentation on the P4MERGE variable for more information how this tool will be called (you may need to wrap it in a script if it doesn't follow the `base theirs yours merged` calling convention): https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v17.1/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/P4MERGE.html

Comment: Thanks Sam. This will only prevents getting the latest version of the opened files. However, what I am looking for is to *merge* the binary files safely, such that I get the changes done by my coworkers while keeping my local changes

Comment: Ah, your question was phrased around not overwriting local changes.  I'll add a note on merging.

Comment: You may be out of luck if these are Word documents, unless you've developed your own Word doc merge tool: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/3-way-merge-office-documents/2d3964c0-723e-49f4-8aa9-15bf97470ed1

Comment: So unless I have my custom merge tool, I have to backup my local changes, then get the latest version, then manually figure out the changes and include them with my local changes, then submit all.

Comment: Yes.  If you have a tool that automates it, `p4 resolve` will invoke it for you, but I don't think that tool exists for a Word doc.  I would not recommend using a Word doc for data that needs to be edited concurrently; there are literally a hundred better options.  :)